# Spring Maven Thymeleaf open login page as default when deploy to Heroku

Tags: spring

As far as I know, spring security will automatically display login page. But I don't know how to modify it to open login page only when anonymous user open the app and browser to others URL that have not been permitted. So when I deploy my app to Heroku, it opens the login page as default, what I want is to make it open index page since anonymous user can have access to index page. Below here is my WebSecurityConfig. I'm using Spring boot with Maven and Thymeleaf template.

```
     @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
    // Allow anonymous to access resource
    .antMatchers("/css/**","/js/**","/images/**","/fonts/**").permitAll()
    // Allow anonymous to access index page
    .antMatchers("/index","/login","/home", "/service","/lessons","/portfolio","/blog","/contact","/signIn").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
  .logout()
      .permitAll();
}
```

Comment: it's `and().antMatchers("/index","/login","/home", "/service","/lessons","/portfolio","/blog","/contact","/signIn").permitAll()` then   `.antMatchers("/PROTECTED_URLS/**").authenticated()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but When I go to localhost:8080. it still automatically opens Login page even in my controller, I already handled it  @RequestMapping("/")
 public String home(Model model) {
  return "redirect:index";
 }

Comment: Oh, I found out the solution, Now when I look at back my controller, It handle the path "/", so obviously I have not configured it in andMatchers. So, the solution is just add "/" to antMatchers. Anyways, thank you for your answer again!